# Calling a function directly while passing parameters Swift

Tags: swift

Does Swift support direct calling of functions as parameter values without instantiation? Here's an example:

```
  static func findById(id: Int) -> MyObject { return myObject }

  //calling the function above in a constructor of an object
  let list = listAll (id: row[id], myObject: MyObjectDao.findById(row[id])) // this give me an error when I try it.
```

Now the only way I can do this is by creating a constant and then passing its value to the constructor.

```
 let myObj = MyObjectDao.findById(row[id])
 let list = listAll (id: row[id], myObject: myObj) // This works
```

Comment: you missed a closing bracket at the end

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: @RJE The closing bracket was a mistake on my side while typing it here. That's not the issue. The closing bracket is in there. It doesn't event pickup the methods I am supposed to be calling.

Comment: Sorry, what is listAll?